# How to use an AsyncTask with urlconnection which is required to insert return?

Tags: java, android

I want to use `AsyncTask` to connect with the server but I got error `ondoInBackground`. The error required that `java.lang.string` so how can I improve the code in `Update()`? How to insert "Return" in `Update()` method?

```
public void Update(final String urlString){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.connect();

                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write("name=abc");
                writer.close();

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder .append(line);
                    }
                     String result = stringBuilder .toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...url) {
        return Update(url[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.d("TAG", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to use AsyncTask with urlconnection which requird to insert return

You need to return a string in your **`Update()`** method

Also no need to use another `Thread` in your `Update()` method because `AsyncTask` already runs in the background

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 public String Update(final String urlString){

        String result="";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.connect();

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            writer.write("name=abc");
            writer.close();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder .append(line);
                }
                result = stringBuilder .toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...url) {
            return Update(url[0]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Log.d("TAG", result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to start AsyncTask:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.execute(URL);
```

Note that: Using AsyncTask you should not create a new Thread in the *Update(URL)* method

Answer (score 0):

```
extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
```

Here String means that AsynkTask waits for a String type in Return.

```
protected String doInBackground(String...url) {
    return Update(url[0]);
}
```

Already in a separate thread. Just delete it from a method.

ps. Don't use AsynkTask for connections with the server. (it's an unstable thing with Activity lifecycle )